# What else can rid the fishy smell of fish besides Casein?

Tags: fish, smell

ATK says TMAO binds to casein but is there a dairy-free alternative that can bind to TMA?

Comment: Cauliflower smells fishy?

Comment: I'm also surprised by your cauliflower reference. If you are tasting something common to both fish and cauliflower, it's possible that it's not TMAO and thus casein won't help. For example, to me fishy smell is as much about the omega-3 oils as TMAO, and flax oil smells like fish to me.

Comment: I'm just taking it out since none of us have any idea what you're talking about, and we can at least potentially have a useful answer to the rest of the question.

Comment: I was referring to the TMA and sulfur content in cauliflower which causes the same "fishy" odor in fish.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't been able to find anything else that binds with TMA other than from dairy products, thus no substitutes.

I have found several suggestions for getting rid of the fishy smell and taste. These include:

• Soaking fish in water with lemon juice added
• Soaking fish in water with salt added
• Soaking fish in  soda such as Mountain Dew or Sprite (look  [here](http://www.crappie.com/crappie/cooking-crappie/140741-removing-strong-fishy-taste/)  )

As per the comments above, I don't get the cauliflower thing.

Comment: Cauliflower has TMA which fish equally does

Comment: @Peet Please provide a link to your source.